# RoboVM not working on JDK 1.8.0 b112

Tags: eclipse, robovm

I'm running Eclipse with RoboVM plugin and I wanted to try IOSDemo sample project described on robovm.org (http://www.robovm.org/docs.html). When creating the project in Eclipse and running it I got following error message.

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching IOSDemo".
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method java.lang.Object.clone()Ljava/lang/Object; from class soot.toolkits.scalar.LocalSplitter
```

I found out that it's related to JDK version (I'm running JDK 8.0 ea, build 112). When running on JDK 1.7.0_45 and building the project on cmd line it builds and runs OK.

Is it known problem, is there any workaround or fix? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is most probably due to a bug [1] in the recent early access builds of Java8. It looks like the bug was resolved a few days ago but as far as I can see the fix didn't make it into the b113 build. Please use the latest Java7 release or an earlier Java8 EA build until a Java8 build is available with this fix included.

[1] https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8026394